# Overheating Lenovo Laptop

Tags: laptop, temperature, fancontrol

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad Edge S430. I experienced maybe three abrupt poweroffs with this laptop and the reason is very likely overheating. I eventually installed `psensor` to monitor my problem, and I'm getting 90 degrees +.

How can I fix this overheating problem?

Comment: If you want to describe a solution you have found, you should describe a problem, press Answer button and write a solution there. You may and should answer your own questions. You can still edit this one or do you want me to do it for you?

Comment: And its becoming a mantra: "If your notebook overheats in Linux only, first check video cards, for duality is their nature"

Comment: If you want to share a solution to a problem you have had on this site we still need questions to be questions and answers to be answers. But, there is nothing to stop you from posing the problem as a question and asking for a solution; then posting the solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>The text below has been taken from the OP's question and posted as an answer.</sup>

Installing cpufrequtils with

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
```

should lower the temperature, and improve battery life.

Even after this, it may stay at 70°C and occasionally surge to above 90°C which is quite bad for the hardware.

My final solution was to use `thinkfan`, to control the fan better. It now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For your overheating problem (uninstall all previous drivers you have):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

if it doesnt solve the problem then you must install everything:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340 nvidia-settings-340 nvidia-prime
```

if this one doesnt work then:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime
```

Then go to nvidia drivers setting page and set intel gpu for normal use. Prime is a package for hybrid systems like yours.

To extend the battery life greatly do the following:

TLP helps laptop reduce the ammount of power consumed in a much more efficient way than any other:

First: Uninstall laptop mode tools

```
sudo apt-get remove laptop-mode-tools
```

Then install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
Finally start it:

sudo tlp start
```